# Help with ocean current details on my terrestrial planet

Tags: science-based, climate, ocean, currents

I'm re-visiting the surface ocean currents on my world and was wondering about a few things. I know Ocean circulation is very complex and hard to say definitively what would happen but I think it's still fun to think/talk about. I've attached a map of the world with ocean currents and areas I'm thinking about highlighted (wind patterns in the background). For reference the circumference is 1.27x that of earths so the scale is a bit larger. Love to hear any thoughts.

[image: Map with currents]

Green: I'm not sure what way currents in these inland seas would rotate, I'm guessing the westerlies on the north coast of the northern sea would drive the rotation and the opposite for the southern sea. This does mean the currents run opposite to each other where the seas meet, however I'm thinking the connection point is so small it doesn't really matter.

Purple: I'm not sure If the westerly winds in the Ferrel cell would be enough to split this ocean gyre like this. I was watching Artifexians video on currents and he split all his currents at this latitude, however, some other people have told me that currents don't really split like that. There is also some landmass pushing the currents offshore, maybe that would help.

Yellow: I think this is the part I'm most confused about since it's a bit of a strange area (pole image attached to see it clearer).  It looks to me that the currents would come in to the sea at the south pole via the larger gap but then the water would obviously have to go somewhere so I've got it kind of awkwardly exiting the ocean through the smaller gaps. Maybe currents in this sea wouldn't really connect to the outer surface currents.

[image]

Finally, Do you think I should figure out the annual changes in the ocean currents? I've seen some people do it. How much of the overall flow and characteristics actually change in summer vs winter?

Any other thoughts are also welcome.

Comment: I think the best way to find an answer for your question is to look at ocean currents from our world. And then come back to ask anything you are still confused about. And while I really would like to give you an answer I really have no idea of ocean currents so my answer would be inaccurate at best.